# Write DDL to .sql file using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I am trying to extract the DDL of tables and store it in .sql files using pandas

The code I have tried is :

```
query = "show table tablename"
df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
df.to_csv('xyz.sql', index=False, header=False, quoting=None)
```

This creates a .sql file with the DDL like this -

```
" CREATE TABLE .....
.... ; "
```

How do I write the file without the quotes, like -

```
CREATE TABLE .....
    .... ;
```

Comment: Please tag with an RDBMS vendor, such as sqlite / mariadb / mysql / postgres, as appropriate.

Comment: Seems you intend to set `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` (setting to None defaults to QUOTE_MINIMAL). But then you may have an issue with delimiters needing to be escaped. Bigger question is why use Pandas or CSV when you don't really want a dataframe or CSV? Just use the database driver's cursor methods to fetch result rows and file write method to output.

Answer (score 0):

Given a string `s`, such as "CREATE ...",
one can delete double-quote characters with:

```
        s = s.replace('"', '')
```

And don't forget
[maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans),
which (with `translate`) is very good at efficiently
deleting unwanted characters from very long strings.

Comment: That will require me to iterate through the created file. Is it possible to do it before writing to the file? i.e. before `df.to_csv('xyz.sql', index=False, header=False, quoting=None)`

Comment: You might wish to [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function which removes unwanted characters. You might also choose to [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) more of the code you're currently running, but that is entirely up to you. The details you reveal will affect the quality of the solutions proposed.